# Remove array of entries from another array

Tags: indexing

I've got 2 arrays

```
    a=(1,2,3,4,5)
    b=(2,4)
```

the output should be

```
    c=(1,3,5)
```

(wich should be the result of a-b)

I've tried using

```
    unset a[${b}]
```

any ideas?

what I have working now is a loop that runs trough 700,000 iterations

Comment: Bash? Processing a 700k-sized array might not be a good thing to do in bash.

Comment: People: [bash scripting is 100% on topic here!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807/85695) Please stop voting to close such questions.

Comment: Do you need to preserve order and/or duplicates ?

Comment: Could you clarify what programming language you are using? Those are not arrays in bash .

Comment: thanks alot for responding, however i did manage to for example do this in one line:

`printf '%s\n' "${filelines[@]}" > resultfile.xml`

wich used to be:

`for string in "${filelines[@]}"
do
        string > resultfile.xml
done`

the one liner resulted in a cignificant improvement
im hoping to find a one liner (with maybe a different command) to (hopefuly) achieve a cignificant improvement in my array problem

Comment: @dtb I have no idea what your comment means. What does printing to a file have to do with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if you want to do this for 700,000 iterations, you *really* should look into something other than bash. Also, what you show is not an array in bash, it's a string<sup>1</sup>. Arrays are separated by spaces, not commas.

That said, here's a bash way, assuming true arrays:

```
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=(2 4)
c=( $(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}" | sort | uniq -u) )
```

If you actually have comma-separated strings and not arrays, use this instead:

```
a=(1,2,3,4,5)
b=(2,4)
c=( $(sed 's/,/\n/g' <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}") | sort | uniq -u) )
```

Alternatively, you could use perl instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @A=(1,2,3,4,5);
my @B=(2,4);
my %k;
map{$k{$_}++} (@A,@B);
my @C=grep($k{$_}==1,keys(%k));
print "@C\n";
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Strictly speaking, it's an array with one element but that is essentially the same as a string as far as bash is concerned.</sub>

Comment: For bash solution, note that if b contains elements that are not in a, you will have them in c. Fox example: a=(1 2 3 4 5), b=(2 4 6) -> c=(1,3,5,6)

Answer (score 1):

The `perl` way. This script displays all elements in array `a`, which are also contained in array `b`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5);
my @b = (2,4,7,8,9,10);

# Create a hashmap with the entries in b as keys,
# but without values for the keys for a better lookup
# (exists ($hash{$element}))
my %hash;
@hash{@b}=();

foreach my $element (@a) {print "$element " unless exists($hash{$element})}
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
1 3 5
```

Comment: @kos Ok you were faster with bash, here is the perl way :)

Comment: thanks alot for responding, however i did manage to for example do this in one line:

'printf '%s\n' "${filelines[@]}" > resultfile.xml'

wich used to be:

'for string in "${filelines[@]}"
do
        string > resultfile.xml
done'

the one liner resulted in a cignificant improvement
im hoping to find a one liner (with maybe a different command) to (hopefuly) achieve a cignificant improvement in my array problem

Answer (score 1):

The complexity the task (O(N^2)) cannot be reduced; assuming only what has been explicitly given (i.e. no hypothesis for the values of both array `a` and `b`) the code below will just check if each value present in `a` is also present in `b`, and if the value is present, it will break the inner `for` loop (the only optimization possible with the given hypothesis) and add the value to `c`; with more clues about the contents of the arrays `a` and `b` (i.e. if the values in each array might be repeated and if the arrays are sorted), there might be some more room for improvement:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=(2 4)
for i in ${a[@]}
do
match=0
    for j in ${b[@]}
    do
        if [ "${i}" == "${j}" ]
        then
            match=1
            break
        fi
    done
if [ "${match}" == 0 ]
then
    c+=($i)
fi
done
echo ${c[@]}
```

Comment: You were again faster =)

Comment: `echo ${#c[@]}` gives `1`.

Comment: @A.B. This might have something to do with a silly parameter expansion, but what's your point? Here you want `echo ${c[@]}`

Comment: `c` isn't an array.

Comment: @A.B. You're right, I forgot `()` indeed

Comment: thanks alot for responding, however i did manage to for example do this in one line:

printf '%s\n' "${filelines[@]}" > resultfile.xml

wich used to be:

for string in "${filelines[@]}"
do
        string > resultfile.xml
done

the one liner resulted in a cignificant improvement
im hoping to find a one liner (with maybe a different command) to (hopefuly) achieve a cignificant improvement in my array problem

Answer (score 1):

In `python`, entries like:

```
a=(1,2,3,4,5)
b=(2,4)
```

are iterables and known as [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Your task can be easily done in `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b = (2, 4)
c = tuple(i for i in a if i not in b)
print c
```

**Output :**

```
(1, 3, 5)
```

Here we have found the values of the tuple `a`, that do not exist in tuple `b` and put them in another tuple `c`. Also note that this operation will be [fast and memory efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/628903/3789550) for larger data sets as we have used python [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: For simple datasets, tuples are not noticeably faster at iterating in my experience, but definitely more memory efficient and faster creation time due to being immutable.

Comment: @NGRhodes Its not about tuples actually, what i meant is generators are faster & memory efficient than list comprehension for larger data sets..  :)

Answer (score 0):

@terdon's accepted answer doesn't actually *remove* items from `a` that are also in `b`, but rather concatenates both lists and removes non-unique values. This is a huge difference when `b` includes items that are not in `a`: `c` will contain values that are in `b`, but not in `a`.

Here's a pure Bash solution for actually *removing* items from `a` that are also in `b` (note the additional `6` in `b`):

```bash
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=(2 4 6)
c=( $(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}" "${b[@]}" | sort | uniq -u) )
```

`c` will consist of `1 3 5` and exclude the unexpected `6`.

If your array items might contain whitespaces, use `mapfile` to construct `Array3` instead, as suggested by [@David on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312762/compare-difference-of-two-arrays-in-bash/69590273#comment132002452_69590273):

```bash
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=(2 4 6)
mapfile -t c < <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}" "${b[@]}" | sort | uniq -u)
```

Please note: This assumes that all values in `a` are unique. Otherwise they won't show up in `c`. If `a` contains duplicate values, you must remove the duplicates first (note the duplicate `1` in `a`; possibly use `mapfile` if your items contain whitespaces):

```bash
a=(1 1 2 3 4 5)
b=(2 4 6)
c=( $({ printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | sort -u; printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}" "${b[@]}"; } | sort | uniq -u) )
```

If you want to replicate the duplicates in `a` to `c`, go with @kos' answer. The same is true if `a` and `b` are huge: this is a very inefficient solution for a lot of items, even though it's negligible for a few items (<100). If you need to process huge arrays don't use Bash.